# how to capture last word after hyphens to redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have lots of urls like `domain/dir1/dir2/word1-word2-word3/number.html`
I will convert them to `domain/dir1/dir2/word1-word2-word3-number` and this go to redirect to url `domain/file.php?id=number`

Which could be the regex to capture the last chain of numbers after - for the redirect?

Thanks in advance.

Until now my test were unsuccelful .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on your question, maybe a few more examples might be useful, but "to get everything from the last `-` to the end", you can do:

- [`-[^-]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/B5WE8p/1)

[image]

Meaning, get a `-`, then get one or more non-`-`'s until the end. Is that what you're looking for?